# Why do the vertices when merged move to a weird position?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I am trying to model a face and joined two parts together. I want to join vertices together at the area where they are not connected. When I use `M -> Merge -> Merge At Center` the vertices both move to a weird position and don't just snap together. When I move the result vertice, I still get a dent in the model.

**I tried :**

- Select A first then B, or B first then A
- Magnet/Snap, move them close together
- `S -> Y -> 0`
- Select A then B -> `F`
- Removed the Mirror Modifier
- Removed the Subdivision Surface Modifier

How do I get the vertices to merge together where they are and make the area smooth so that everything looks level? In the tutorial I am following, this seems to work flawlessly.

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

[image: third image]

[image: fourth image]

[image]

Comment: hello maybe you have an inverted face? Select all and press Shift N?

Comment: ... also better to enable Face Orientation under Overlayes to see if Shift+N operator is not switching correctly faced one to opposite at the same time :)

Comment: @moonboots I tried that and that didn't have an impact when I merged the vertices.

Comment: @moonboots will try again with the other suggestion you mentioned!

Comment: could you please share your file? only keep several faces... https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I've added and uploaded the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deactivate the *On Cage* option of your *Subdivision Surface* modifier, it will allow you to see your mesh as it really is. As you see all these vertices are disjointed, which make a riped edge, once you'll have merged them your surface will look normal. To merge them you can either use the *Merge* function or enable the *Auto Merge* and the *Snap to Vertex* options:

[image]